# Bootcamp windows in OSX

Tags: windows, macos, mac, multi-boot, boot-camp

So I do not have access to the firmware password of my MacBook Pro '13. I was wondering that if I install windows over bootcamp would prompt me for my firmware password at any point of the installation process. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does.  The firmware password's entire job is to keep you from booting off alternate media.  So if you have a firmware password set and you don't know what it is, you will not be able to install Windows.

Comment: Is there a way to remove/bypass the firmware password when installing windows?

Comment: If you have a 2010 model or older, you can follow [this article](http://www.cnet.com/news/use-the-calculator-to-reveal-a-macs-firmware-password/) to reset it.  If your model is 2011 or newer, only an Apple store can reset it.